# Blustery old bird idiom

Tags: idioms

There is an idiom/euphemism for a person who angers, puffs up, blustery.  I am searching for the name of that bird. Or maybe a term for this behavior?

Comment: If the intention is to ridicule the person, you might say they puffed up like a turkey cock. The term has a dictionary meaning: "a pompous or self-important person."

Comment: Banty rooster perhaps, esp. for someone short of stature.

Comment: @KarlG Coot, certainly; perhaps even loon.

Comment: There's no reason to believe that it references a particular breed of bird.  Lots of birds exhibit the behavior, and anyone with modest wildlife exposure would appreciate the intended meaning without having to know the breed.

Comment: @HotLicks So "ruffle one's feathers" would be a good suggestion, no? Only it doesn't quite hit it...doesn't it imply annoying someone, rather the reaction?

Comment: @Cascabel - A "blustery old bird" is presumably that even when not currently "ruffled".

Answer (score 0):

The term **to ruffle** comes to mind:  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ruffled)  One sense: To erect (the feathers).  Another sense:

> To become annoyed or flustered

As in:

> What teacher doesn't ruffle when students act up in class?

There are various idiom of **ruffle** too.

Comment: Ruffle is great. Referring to someone as a curmudgeon works well too.

Answer (score 0):

One evocative option is the phrase "like a bantam cock on a dunghill." [*Common Phrases: And Where They Come From*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sm0TCk5fSpYC&pg=PA78&dq=%22cock+on+a+dunghill%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvz8OFlsfhAhVFo54KHTM9C-kQ6AEITjAG#v=onepage&q=%22cock%20on%20a%20dunghill%22&f=false) provides some context for this expression's emergence into popular use (albeit as a side-passage in a discussion focused on the expression "I'll be hanged if I do"):

> [John] Thelwall was an English poet of liberal political views. He disagreed violently with King George III's tyrannical rule, helped organize the Jacobin Societies in 1791, and was an active worker in the Society of Friends. He wrote and lectured against the king and supported the cause of American independence. During a lecture at the Capel Court Society, he likened a crowned despot to a **bantam cock on a dunghill**." This caught the fancy of radicals of the day and, not surprisingly, enraged the king.

The simile also appears in Frances Hodgson Burnett, [*His Grace of Osmonde*](https://books.google.com/books?id=m5YnDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA68&dq=%22on+a+dunghill%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjti67Kx83hAhXPi54KHTPcD_4Q6AEIWDAI#v=onepage&q=%22on%20a%20dunghill%22&f=false) (1914), where the person so described is not a king but a viscount:

> "I'm damned if we scapegraces have not missed thy good-looking face. Thou art a fine fellow, Roxholm—and good-natured—ay, and modest, too—for all thy beauty and learning. Many a man, with half thou hast, would wear grand Court airs to a rattle-pated rascal like Tom Tantillion. Wilford does it—and he is but a Viscount, and for all his straight nose and fine eyes but five feet ten. Good Lord! he looks down on us who did not pass well at the University, like a **cock on a dunghill**."
>
> The Marquess laughed out heartily, having in his mind a lively picture of my Lord Wilford, whose magnificence of bearing he knew well.

And again from [*Tiffany Thayer's Three Musketeers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hqdRAQAAMAAJ&q=%22on+a+dung+hill%22&dq=%22on+a+dung+hill%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi49ejpyc3hAhVFvZ4KHSuKBicQ6AEIPTAD) (1939):

> Notwithstanding his respect for this holy man, de Rocheforte was reminded of a **bantam cock crowing on a dung hill**.